# Partial query to DB returns full column, need data row by row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

View

```
<%= link_to "Link", {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}, :update => "Ajaxcall", :remote => true %>
```

Controller

```
def AjaxView
  @vars= Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varName=> "one" },:select=>(params[:col]))
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :layout=>false }
end
end
```

AjaxView.js.erb

```
$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var", 
                                           :collection => @vars)) %>");
```

_var.html.erb

```
<%= var.col1 %>
```

Now it returns all values from Column, need them one by one ?

Current output is: "amit1 amit2 amit3 amit4" as single string
I want to get these values one by one, so that I can map it with Div id and publish them in Grid

Desired Output is : "amit1"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please, add current and desired output.

Comment: You should have the server output JSON that the client can parse. What is `var` in the above code?  I think you're showing us pseudo-code, but removing too much real code in the process.

Comment: Also, what is the ActiveRecord query?

Comment: Eugene, d11wtq I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to alony

Right answer provided by her is

```
  <% @vars[2].col1 %>
```

also in AjaxView.js.erb write,

```
  $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `render(:partial => "var", :collection => @vars)` this way, you actually render that partial for each variable, one by one. So to use this data one by one i think you need one of these:

1) use all the html part you want to add in the partial:
_var.html.erb

```
<td id='<%= var.col1 %>'>    # or whatever attributes you want
   ..
</td>
```

2) iterate the variables directly inside the partial:
AjaxView.js.erb

```
$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");
```

_var.html.erb

```
<% @vars.each do |var| %>
  # do whatever you want
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes, you are rendering a partial for each entry in your `@vars` collection. As the partial contains only one string - for all the records their `col1` is shown consequentially.
So, to make it clear, you want col1 for each entry in `@vars` to be shown in a separate div?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.This is the last work for my grid, please help me in this.

Comment: it gives me this on my "DIV"                                        <div id='' > row1 </div><div id='' > row2 </div><div id='' > row3 </div>

Comment: i thought that's what you were looking for (with good ids of course) as col1 for each entry in @vars is shown in a separate div :) what html would you like to get?

Comment: I guess my id is empty for all three row, which is not the case if I query DB

Comment: I don't need any HTML, I just need plane text, which i will put in <td id="3"> </td> of my table

Comment: ok I'm still not sure I've done what you wanted, but edited the answer :) if incorrect, please specify you task

Comment: No it didn't work, it gave me loop for each varName, What I am missing here is that when I execute this <%= var.col1 %>
 it give me an array, I don't want array. I need that some how it should give me for example, only second match as return of this partial.

Comment: then don't pass a collection to the partial, like this `$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");` and in the partial render only one column: `<% @vars[2].col1 %>`